# Asymptotics for an expression

Tags: analysis

I have a rather silly question, I guess.
Suppose $(1+x)^{2y}\sim 1$ as $y\to\infty$.

Does this imply $x\sim 1/y$ as $y\to\infty$?

Comment: So $x$ is a function of $y$? The answer is no anyways. For example, if $x(y)=0$, this claim is true. Also, $$\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^{2y}=e^2\neq0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $x=x(y) \to 0$ as $y\to +\infty$. Then
$$
(1 + x)^{2y}  = \exp (2y\log (1 + x)) = \exp (2yx + \mathcal{O}(yx^2 )).
$$
So if you want
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to  + \infty } (1 + x)^{2y}  = 1,
$$
you need that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to  + \infty } xy = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to  + \infty } x(y)y = 0,
$$
i.e., that $x=o(1/y)$ as $y\to +\infty$. So $x$ must tend to $0$ faster than $1/y$ does.